# Who created the xmax 3D file format, and what can open it?

Tags: 3d

A client recently handed me a rogue 3D file with an extension of "xmax".  No one I know, including Google and Bing, seem to know what kind of file this is or what can open it.  I imagine maybe it was proprietary.  Opening the file with a hex editor shows that it has a FourCC code of "XMAX" followed by a few bytes then "VER" and what is clearly a 32-bit 0x00000001 in network order.  The presence of a fourcc would indicate that the file wasn't simply renamed from a different format with the wrong extension.   Any ideas of where this file came from?

Comment: Stack Overflow's SEO is working well.  This question already comes up in third place when I search "file extension xmax" in Google, trying to find your answer.

Comment: So, the file is binary and can't yet be opened.  Are you certain it's a 3D file?  I found "a platform for creating thin client custom XML editors" named XMAX: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMetaL (and apparently it's also the name of a mod for a game called Titan Quest:  http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/titan-quest-xmax-mod.186020217/)

Comment: Our conclusion was that it was a proprietary format.  There was only one model in this format, we worked around it.

Answer (score 0):

Zbrush creates an XMAX file when it transfers a file to 3ds Max.  "GoZ", the extension that allows for transfer between the programs, creates a XMAX file in the gozprojects folder \Users\Public\Pixologic\GoZProjects\Default.